# Haar Filtered Images

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I use Lena image 256x256 uint8 and I've applied Haar filter

```
dwt2(startImage,'haar','mode','sym');
```

when I see the horizontal, vertical and diagonal filtered images , I see Lena details but as if they were in black and white, and the correspondent matrices have negatives entries (!). And if I see the average image, I just see a white square.
Searching for help in Matlab 7.11, I saw the example, it works for a MAT file, and using wcodemat function, but I need to load the image via

```
J = imread('Lena.tif');
```

beacuse I am planing to work with a great number of images in order to train a discriminant etc.
How can I get the scaled images correctly?
Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to use mat2grey in each level of decomposition, that's it.